# How to store the widget objects for a nested window?

Tags: python, tkinter

My application is made up of about 50 elements (nested Frames and Labels), similar to

[image]

(the green rectangles are Labels, the blue lines - Frames)

It is now a few hours I am juggling with code to find the best storage format for the window objects. I am seeking to learn what is the commonly used data structure for such an application, so far I tried the following ones, by order of sophistication:

- the `Tkinter` examples usually use bare variables. This is OK when there are just a few widgets, the 50 in my case are not practical to describe that way
- a flat list to which I would append the object when it is generated. It requires "manually" maintaining a strict correspondence table between indexes and widgets
- a list made up of the two following elements, that solution is not easy to maintain either and each object is a long chain of indexes and keys

  - `{'id': <Frame> , children=list()}`, the `children` are made up of this or the next structure
  - `<Label>`, it will not have children

I think a tree-like structure would be best but I will use whatever is usually chosen to store these kind of strictures.

Comment: Why do you need to keep references for them? Tkinter already keeps track of parent/child relationships for you.

Comment: I will have functions updating specific Labels via .configure() so I need to access them via a reference,  right? Other than this I would have not needed to keep a list so if there is a better solution I am all for it.

Comment: Do these label have logical names(eg: name, address, contact info, or make, model, color, price)? Do you need to keep track of the frames? What you are doing _seems_ highly unusual since there are so few details being provided. There is no general solution for such a UI.

Comment: Yes, they have a logical name; Actually the application is a dashboard without any interaction with the user, it just displays information in Labels. I looked at this from another perspective overnight, following your comment, and I will keep a dictionary of `StringVar()` and not keep track of all the components.